# Android: How can I retain the state of an object on back button Action bar and back button of device

Tags: java, android

I have ActivityA and ActivityB. ActivityB is called from ActivityA.

I wanted to retain the object of ActivityA, when I press back button of ActionBar or back button of device.

I have created a Singleton object to save my object and to get my object.

onPause() I am saving the object and onResume() method I am getting the object.

My problem here is the behaviour is different, the object that I get when back button of Action (in ActivityB) is different from the object that I get when back button of back button is clicked.

Here is the code:

```
protected void onPause() {
    //resetSort();
    super.onPause();
    MySingleton.getInstance().setMyObject(myObject);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myObject = MySingleton.getInstance().getMyObject();
}
```

Here is my manifest file.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Code from ActivityB:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Any solution is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Depending on your code, the actual control flow may be different from 2 back methods. Remember if you click device back button, the control would be like ActivityB onPause() -> ActivityB onStop() -> ActivityA onStart() -> ActivityA onResume(). so which activity your onPause and onResume() are in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way is to use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). It's both thread safe and remains even if your app is killed off.

Google's [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) guide is also definitely worth a look if you haven't had a chance to review it yet.

To save a String you would use:

```
String str = "abc";
getSharedPreferences("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("String Name", str).commit();
```

And then to retrieve it:

```
String str = getSharedPreferences("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("String Name", "default string")
```

Comment: Thanks I understood. But I wanted to save and get custom object not the String.

Comment: Could you please update your question to include more information about your activities and singleton? If you're manipulating the object in your activities you may want to consider having the singleton do it instead. That will ensure it always returns the correct object.